# Google Sheets =MONTH works but MONTH in QUERY does not

Tags: google-sheets, formatting, date-formatting

Google Sheets: I checked my column of dates is in `DATE` format not `Automatic`.

When I use `MONTH` in a cell I get the correct month back from that column.

When I do a `QUERY` such as `=query('Main'!A1:M20,"select MONTH(M)",1)` I get `#VALUE!` with the comment:

> Unable to parse the Function `QUERY` for parameter 2: Can't perform the function `MONTH` on a column that is not a `DATE` or a `DATETIME` column

Why does `QUERY` not see the column as being in `DATE` format but `=MONTH` does?

Comment: There isn't enough details in order to be able to give you a precise answer. Please added some sample values directly to the question and create a demo spreadsheet to reproduce the problem. Ref. [mcve]

Answer (score 5):

months in a query are numbered and starts from 0, therefore, you will need to add +1 to get the first month and then do a weird logic: "where month1=month2" to get february (`month(A)+1=3` for march, `month(A)+1=12` for december, etc.)

```
=QUERY(A1:D10, "select A,B,C,D where month(A)+1=2", 1)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you  that is correct but does not address my question. Outside QUERY the =MONTH function works with DATE format data in my column. But inside QUERY the MONTH function fails because it says my data is not in DATE format. This is not about the numbering of months.

Comment: well, again... =MONTH() outside of query is not same as month() inside the query. first one is a regular formula and when month() in query thats just a parameter for query

Comment: I agree with you. I seek hints for how to get the parameter MONTH() in QUERY to work with the same data that already works with the regular formula =MONTH()

Comment: it's usually done by interupting query params like: `"select * where A = '&month(today())&'""`

Comment: Column M has DATE format data. =query('Main'!A1:M20,"select MONTH(M)",1) is intended to pull out the month from Column M only and return just that column of data. What am I missing? Google Sheets is telling me that Column M does not have DATE format. Really appreciate any insights you may have.

Comment: you kinda do miss it... only "MONTH(M)" is not a valid command. as you describe it I guess you just wana do this? `=ARRAYFORMULA(MONTH(M1:M20))`

Comment: Thanks for not giving up on this. I have been asked to move our conversation to chat mode but my reputation is too recent to allow this.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NNLMxShawNzMum11mkSX5yURhw0agNqEu0BhKXjcWio/edit